# Posting automatically to Facebook Page without authentication in a browser

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post as a page (which I'm an admin of) without authenticating myself in a browser? I have seen that, for example, [Facebook Python SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) allows you to interact with Facebook API but it needs to get an authorization via a browser. Instead, I'd like to do that automatically.

I have created an APP so I have an `APP_ID`, an `USER_TOKEN` and using `'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET` I got an Oauth Access Token but I can't find a way to achieve complete automation in posting a message to my page, so how can I accomplish that?

I just read about [Authentication for Devices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/) but I'm still not sure that it's what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: You want a page access token, so see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: Good, and then what should I do? I don't think 'server-side' allows me to do what I want.

Comment: Where else do you want to use _python_ – client-side …? But anyway, for the most parts it doesn’t matter if you talk to the API from server or client side.

Comment: I want to use the API server-side but I don't want to authorize using the browser because I won't have a browser in my server. Basically, I want to post some updates to my page but without "human intervention"

Comment: So, you get the page access token, and use it in your server-side post request … where’s the problem?

Comment: The problem is that a server-side request requires authentication via a browser (step 2): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

Comment: Yes, _once_, to get the page access token. But you don’t even have to build that into your app in code, you can f.e. also use the Graph API Explorer to get a token on-the-fly.

Comment: Right, but those tokens expire (actually, now all of them expire) so I'd have to go through the authentication from time to time.